# RBG to CbyCr conversion code

Tags: c

I am wondering why this code does not work.  Basically it is supposed to convert between RGB and CbYCr.  When I convert from RGB to CbYCr then back to RGB I do not get the original RGB values.  What is wrong with this code?

#define MIN(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))

struct _rgb {
`int R;`
`int G;`
`int B;`
};

typedef struct _rgb rgb;

struct _cbycr {
`int Cb;`
`int Y;`
`int Cr;`
};

typedef struct _cbycr cbycr;

void cbycr2rgb(rgb *c, double Y, double Cb, double Cr) {
`int r = (int)(Y + 1.40200 * (Cr - 0x80));`
`int g = (int)(Y - 0.34414 * (Cb - 0x80) - 0.71414 * (Cr - 0x80));`
`int b = (int)(Y + 1.77200 * (Cb - 0x80));`
`c->R = MAX(0, MIN(255, r));`
`c->G = MAX(0, MIN(255, g));`
`c->B = MAX(0, MIN(255, b));`
}

void rgb2cbycr(cbycr *c, int R, int G, int B) {
`c->Y  = (int)(0.299   * R + 0.587   * G + 0.114   * B);`
`c->Cb = (int)(-0.16874 * R - 0.33126 * G + 0.50000 * B);`
`c->Cr =(int)(0.50000 * R - 0.41869 * G - 0.08131 * B);`
}

int main() {
`cbycr _cbycr;`
`rgb _rgb;`
`_rgb.R = 50;`
`_rgb.G = 50;`
`_rgb.B = 50;`
`rgb2cbycr(&_cbycr, _rgb.R, _rgb.G, _rgb.B);`
`cbycr2rgb(&_rgb, _cbycr.Y, _cbycr.Cb, _cbycr.Cr);`
`printf("rgb=%d %d %d\n", _rgb.R, _rgb.G, _rgb.B);`
`return 0;`
}

output: rgb=0 185 0

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger (or print out intermediate variables) to find out?

Comment: You are completely mixing up double and int, not paying attention to a value range of 0..1 vs 0..255

Answer (score 2):

The JFIF usage of JPEG allows Y'CbCr where Y', Cb and Cr have the full 8-bit range of 0-255. It achieves this by adding a bias of `0x80` to the Cb and Cr values. The `cbycr2rgb` function is (presumably correctly) trying to subtract this bias value from Cb and Cr, but `rgb2cbycr` did not add it on, so it fails to return the original RGB values.